# Crash when creating UIImage by data

Tags: ios, swift, memory

I'm trying to allocate `UIImage` by `NSData` on background.

```
        let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)

        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue) {
            let image = UIImage(data: data)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                //displaying
            }
        }
```

But I'm receiving crash with message: "NSAllocateMemoryPages(1907982) failed"

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2):

Not so much an answer as a hint maybe, but too long for a comment so I'll post it here.

I found [this post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6564) on Apple Developer Forums where some poor soul has problems similar to yours. The exception he/she receives is:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** NSAllocateMemoryPages(18446744073709551615) failed'

And the answer to him/her is:

> This message means that someone has tried to allocate a memory block of size 18446744073709551615.

In your case, that must mean that you (in the attempt to create an image) have tried to allocate a memory block of size 1907982. Maybe that is too much? How do you receive the data and what is it?